# Is it appropriate to create controls in the CurPageChanged procedure?

Tags: inno-setup

I have code in CurPageChanged that adds a button to the license window. My CurPageChanged starts like this:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var Button123 TButton;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpLicense then begin
    Button123 := TButton.Create(WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Parent);
```

My question is wouldn't that create a button each time the page is changed to the wpLicense page? So if a user clicks past the license dialog, then goes back to it, wouldn't that create another button? How can I ensure that only one button is created? What I'm looking for is the most appropriate procedure from which to add a control --once-- to an existing wp. Thanks

Comment: You could create the button in the `InitializeWizard` method, and then simply set its visibility in the `CurPageChanged` method. Not sure if that's the best approach though. I get by hacking my way through Inno Setup when necessary. :-)

Comment: @Cody I didn't think I could do that but I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: @Cody, it is the best approach! Actually, the whole wizard form including all the pages is already created at the `InitializeWizard` event time, so I would say it's time to delete my post and let you write your own :-)

Comment: @TLama Thanks for the encouragement! Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is wouldn't that create a button each time the page is changed to the wpLicense page? So if a user clicks past the license dialog, then goes back to it, wouldn't that create another button?

Yes, it would create multiple buttons each time. Because the pages do not get destroyed, the controls on them do not get destroyed. But you can actually take advantage of that fact to create a single control and then show/hide it when necessary.

To start, modify the `InitializeWizard` method, which is called only once *before* the wizard is displayed. Create the button in here, like so:

```delphi
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  MyButton: TButton;
begin
  MyButton := TButton.Create(WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Parent);
  MyButton.Parent := WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Parent;
  MyButton.Top := 0;
  MyButton.Left := 0;
  MyButton.Caption := 'My Custom Button';
  ...
end;
```